# PHP reversing logic of base value + ? = result value

Tags: php, logic, reverse-engineering, division, modulo

I have a base value & the result final changed value how do I reverse calculation to get what division of the changed?
the goal is when I give input the result value, it should give explanation what variable is used to makes the calculation it's like A+?=C

```
<?php
/*this is an behind logic changes example*/
//possible value -2 to 5
$atk    = 0;
$matk   = 1;
$def    = 0;
$aspd   = 0;
$hit    = 0;
$crit   = 0;
$eva    = 0;
$move   = 5;
$hp     = 0;
$ap     = 0;

/*default magic number of base value*/
$base = array(
        "atk"       => 1,
        "matk"      => 8,
        "def"       => 64,
        "aspd"      => 512,
        "hit"       => 4096,
        "crit"      => 32768,
        "eva"       => 262144,
        "move"      => 2097152,
        "hp"        => 16777216,
        "ap"        => 134217728,

);

/*logic method to calculate base value*/
$base_sum=0;
foreach ($base as $key => $val) {
    echo "\n".$key." -> ".$val;
    $base_sum+=$val;
}
echo "\n"."Total -> ".$base_sum;
/*the real base value sum is double of base value*/
$final_base = $base_sum * 2;
echo "\n=================================";
echo "\n"."Base -> ".$final_base;
echo "\n=================================";

/*generated sample changes value*/
$changes = array(
    "atk"       => $atk,
    "matk"      => $matk,
    "def"       => $def,
    "aspd"      => $aspd,
    "hit"       => $hit,
    "crit"      => $crit,
    "eva"       => $eva,
    "move"      => $move,
    "hp"        => $hp,
    "ap"        => $ap
);


/*logic to apply changes in base value sum*/
$change_num = 0;
foreach ($changes as $key => $val) {
    $change_num = $change_num + ($val*$base[$key]);
    echo "\n".$key." -> ".$val."*".$base[$key]." = ".$val*$base[$key];
}
echo "\n"."Changes -> ".$change_num;
echo "\n"."=================================";
$final_change = $final_base + $change_num;
echo "\n"."Final change - > ".$final_change."\n";

?>
```

Output :

```
atk -> 1
matk -> 8
def -> 64
aspd -> 512
hit -> 4096
crit -> 32768
eva -> 262144
move -> 2097152
hp -> 16777216
ap -> 134217728
Total -> 153391689
=================================
Base -> 306783378
=================================
atk -> 0*1 = 0
matk -> 1*8 = 8
def -> 0*64 = 0
aspd -> 0*512 = 0
hit -> 0*4096 = 0
crit -> 0*32768 = 0
eva -> 0*262144 = 0
move -> 5*2097152 = 10485760
hp -> 0*16777216 = 0
ap -> 0*134217728 = 0
Changes -> 10485768
=================================
Final change - > 317269146
```

Expected result when I give input **317269146** the return should be matk = 1, move = 5

Can anyone share any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how you can uniformly determine the modifiers based solely on results. How do you expect to differ between `1*64`, `64*1` or `8*8` if the difference is 64?

Comment: _“Can anyone share any idea?”_ - first you share an actual _explanation_ of the logic behind this, please. `317269146` (you apparently mean the difference to the “base”, so `10485768`) could as well be the result of `matk = 1, eva = 40` - so explain why it is not that, but the other?

Comment: And what does the comment `//possible value -2 to 5` mean? That combinations like `move = 5, crit = -2` could also occur in your “input” data? So the goal would then be to find a combination that assembles the given target value, from the given base values, by applying factors in the range of -2 to 5 to them?

Comment: @CBroe yes that what I mean, I curious the magic number handle role there, it was the maximum value can be set in the variable

Comment: @El_Vanja that was the point, but the actual software can do it, I tried to translate it with the logic given

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Actual software?

Comment: @El_Vanja It was the small toolkit, the dropdown is automatically filled when we put the result value to the textarea, dropdown value contain value -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 here is the snap https://pasteboard.co/JQ0F3U8.png

Comment: Obviously that tool has some rules (for example, it tries to find the largest amounts of largest numbers first or something similar). Knowing how exactly this tool does it would require a) insight into its source code or b) a statistically significant amount of examples so that a definite algorithm can be concluded. Option a) would make this question unnecessary, because if you can read the source code, you don't need to ask, while option b) would be reduced to a math question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer inspired by @El_Vanja which he/she mention about some logic rule, I try to implement the logic then it worked

```
/*reversing the result value back to steps*/
echo "\n"."Reversing value of changes 317269146";
/*find diff = final_change - final_base*/
$change_num = 317269146-306783378;

    $ap_  = intval($change_num / 134217728);
    $ap   = $change_num % 134217728;
    
    $hp_  = intval($ap / 16777216);
    $hp   = $change_num % 16777216;

    $move_  = intval($hp / 2097152);
    $move = $change_num % 2097152;

    $eva_  = intval($move_ / 262144);
    $eva  = $change_num % 262144;

    $crit_  = intval($eva / 32768);
    $crit = $change_num % 32768;
    
    $hit_  = intval($crit / 4096);
    $hit  = $change_num % 4096;
    
    $aspd_ = intval($hit / 512);
    $aspd = $change_num % 512;

    $def_ = intval($aspd / 64);
    $def  = $change_num % 64;

    $matk_ = intval($def / 8);
    $matk = $change_num % 8;

    $atk_ = intval($matk / 1);
    $atk  = $change_num % 1;
       
    echo 
    "\n\n"."atk  -> ".$atk_ .
    "\n"."matk -> ".$matk_.
    "\n"."def  -> ".$def_.
    "\n"."aspd -> ".$aspd_.
    "\n"."hit  -> ".$hit_.
    "\n"."crit -> ".$crit_.
    "\n"."eva  -> ".$eva_.
    "\n"."move -> ".$move_.
    "\n"."hp   -> ".$hp_.
    "\n"."ap   -> ".$ap_;
```

Output

```
Reversing value of changes 317269146

atk  -> 0
matk -> 1
def  -> 0
aspd -> 0
hit  -> 0
crit -> 0
eva  -> 0
move -> 5
hp   -> 0
ap   -> 0
```

The magic number play significant role for the calculation
Thanks!

Comment: it seem still unsolved, can't handle data with negative value :(